# Iterative merge sort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

I am aware of classical recursive approach to sort something by merging.
It yields `O(n * log(n))` complexity, which can be more or less easily shown via recurrence relation.

I've tried to reimplement merge sort in iterative fashion:

```
def atomize(l):
    return list(
        map(
            lambda x: [x],
            l if l is not None else []
        )
    )

def merge(l, r):
    res = []
    while (len(l) + len(r)) > 0:
        if len(l) < 1:
            res += r
            r = []
        elif len(r) < 1:
            res += l
            l = []
        else:
            if l[0] <= r[0]:
                res.append(l.pop(0))
            else:
                res.append(r.pop(0))
    return res

def iter_merge_sort(l):
    atoms = atomize(l) # O(n)
    while len(atoms) > 1: # O(n - 1)
        atoms.append(merge(atoms.pop(0), atoms.pop(0)))
    return atoms[0]
```

...and feels like I am mistaken somewhere, yet I fail to notice exact place. Recursive merge sort splits problem unless list of unsorted values reduces to a list of singletons - single elements that can be compared. That's what `atomize(...)` does: given a list, produces a list of lists-singletons (order `O(n)`).

Obviously, `merge(...)` is `O(n)` as well: ignore for moment that no linked lists are used for concatenation, that's not important here.

Finally.. the `while` block in the `iter_merge_sort(...)` itself takes exactly `n - 1` repetitions, each of which costs at most `O(n)`. Hence, I took `O(n * log(n))` algorithm and "improved" it to be `(n - 1) * n ~ O(n * n)`. Where is my mistake?

Comment: This is a correct upper bound on your runtime. To be more precise, calculate n/2 * T(merge(1)) + n/4 * T(merge(2)) + n/8 *... + 1*T(merge(n/2))
, which is the exact time complexity of your while loop and should give you the expected result (assuming python's list::pop() runs in O(1) which I'm not sure about)

Comment: @Chemistree, indeed, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov - Translate the while loop into a pass count. The first pass will take n/2 iterations to merge all n runs of size 1, that's O(n) complexity for the merges. At that point atoms will contain runs of size 2, and the next pass will take n/4 iterations to merge n/2 runs of size 2 again O(2*n/2) = O(n) complexity for the merges. It will take ceil(log2(n)) passes, each with O(n) time complexity to end up with a single sorted run in atoms of size n, for a total time complexity of O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is entirely correct. The problem lies in that you're using `list.pop(0)` as a way to dequeue, which costs *O(n)* in Python since all items after a popped item of a list have to be copied to the preceding positions.

You can use `collections.deque` in place of list so that you can use the `deque.popleft` method, which costs *O(1)*:

```
from collections import deque

def atomize(l):
    return deque(
        map(
            lambda x: deque([x]),
            l if l is not None else []
        )
    )

def merge(l, r):
    res = deque()
    while (len(l) + len(r)) > 0:
        if len(l) < 1:
            res += r
            r = deque()
        elif len(r) < 1:
            res += l
            l = deque()
        else:
            if l[0] <= r[0]:
                res.append(l.popleft())
            else:
                res.append(r.popleft())
    return res

def iter_merge_sort(l):
    atoms = atomize(l) # O(n)
    while len(atoms) > 1: # O(n - 1)
        atoms.append(merge(atoms.popleft(), atoms.popleft()))
    return list(atoms[0])
```

so that:

```
iter_merge_sort([3,5,1,6,2,1])
```

returns:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```